# Trying to use JavaFX with Scala; getting "Unable to construct Application instance: class javaFXTest.Tests$"

Tags: scala, javafx

I translated a simple HelloWorld application provided by Oracle to Scala (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/hello_world.htm).

It compiles, but gives the above RunTime Exception when I run it. I looked over the 2 other posts on this error via Google, and neither seem to solve my problem:

- [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729362/trying-to-call-a-javafx-application-from-java-nosuchmethodexception) says that I must provide an argument-less constructor when extending `Application`, but Scala creates this automatically. I tried creating one explicitly, but I got the expected "ambiguous occurrence" error.
- The [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599423/unable-to-construct-javafx-application-application-instance) says that the class extending Application must be public, but again, that shouldn't be a problem given classes are by default `public`

If I change `object Tests extends Application` to `class Tests extends Application`, Eclipse can't "find" the entry point, and gives me the error "Selection does not contain a main type". What's the problem? I hope it's not a compatibility issue.

I downloaded both Scala and Java fairly recently (a month or 2 ago), so I should have the latest versions of each.

Any tips here would be appreciated.

```
package javaFXTest

import javafx._
    import application.Application
    import stage.Stage
    import scene.Scene 
    import scene.control.Button
    import scene.layout.StackPane
    import event.ActionEvent
    import event.EventHandler

object Tests extends Application {

    val buttonPressHandler = new EventHandler[ActionEvent] {
        def handle(event: ActionEvent) = {
            println { event }
        }
    }

    //Main entry point
    def start(primaryStage: Stage) = {
        val button = new Button

        button setText "Hello World!"

        button setOnAction buttonPressHandler

        val root = new StackPane

        root.getChildren.add(button)

        val scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300)

        primaryStage setTitle "Hello World!"
        primaryStage setScene scene
        primaryStage.show()


    }

    def main(args: Array[String]) = {
        // `:_*` turns a scala array into a java vararg
        Application launch (args:_*)
    }
```

I just realized after posting this that because I'm using an `object`, it can't be initialized, and won't have a constructor (whoops. My previous constructor test was when I tried using `class` instead of `object`). So the question is now, why can't Eclipse figure out how to run the above code? 
    }

Comment: To make things easier [ScalaFX](http://www.scalafx.org/) exists, and it seems like it's come a long way since I used it.

Comment: Do you know any guides on how to just install it? I just spent the last 4 hours this morning trying to install it, and after having installed both Git and SBT (which were supposed to help), I'm just more confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124657/getting-started-on-scala-javafx-desktop-application-development), I got it working.
The key things to note:

- The class extending Application must be a class, not an object (duh, in retrospect)
- Put the `main` in a companion object of the same name
- `Application launch (args:_*)` needs to be `Application.launch(classOf[Tests],args:_*)` (where `Tests` = Your class).

In the end, this launched correctly:

```
package javaFXTest

import javafx._
    import application.Application
    import stage.Stage
    import scene.Scene 
    import scene.control.Button
    import scene.layout.StackPane
    import event.ActionEvent
    import event.EventHandler


class Tests extends Application {

    val buttonPressHandler = new EventHandler[ActionEvent] {
        def handle(event: ActionEvent) = {
            println { event }
        }
    }

    //Main entry point
    def start(primaryStage: Stage) = {
        val button = new Button

        button setText "Hello World!"

        button setOnAction buttonPressHandler

        val root = new StackPane

        root.getChildren.add(button)

        val scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300)

        primaryStage setTitle "Hello World!"
        primaryStage setScene scene
        primaryStage.show()


    }

}

object Tests {

    def main(args: Array[String]) = {
        // `:_*` turns a scala array into a java vararg
        Application.launch(classOf[Tests],args:_*)
    }

}
```

Hopefully this helps.